# jQuery index function

Tags: jquery, indexing

I think I need to use jQuery's `index()` function but I'm doing it all wrong! I have a bunch of table cells with images inside, and one of them will have a class called "current". How can I tell which image has the class? I need an integer to work with.

I'm thinking something like this but I get "-1", nothing found..

`var prev = $('#full_width_gallery').index('img');`

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: How about `$('img.current')`?

Comment: In the index()function? That doesn't work.

Comment: @Dan Oh I see.. I thought you were trying to select the image seeing _How can I tell which image has the class_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Select the images: `var $images = $('#full_width_gallery img');`
2. Retrieve the index of the image with class ".current": `$images.filter('.current').index();` - this will be the index of that image in $images, not some kind of "global" index!

In total:

```
var index = $('#full_width_gallery img').filter('.current').index();
```

or:

```
var index = $('.current').index('#full_width_gallery img');
```

Comment: Is there a reason to create a var, or would it be just as effective doing `$('#full_width_gallery img').index('.current');`?

Comment: Could I use that like this;

`var $images = $('#full_width_gallery img');
    var current = $images.index('.current');
    alert(current)`

Comment: @Archer That's the same, I just introduced the variable to break it up in two steps.

Comment: `.index` does not work like that. You swapped the order of object/argument.